# how to save data outside subscribe Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am trying to save data received from http get request and save it into another array that belongs to the component

```
getAlerts(){
 this.ChatAlertsService.getAlerts()
        .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log('ngon Init', data);
                this.useralerts=data['result'];
                 console.log('inside subscribe user_alerts', this.useralerts);

            },
            (error) => console.log(error));
    console.log('outside subscribe user_alerts', this.useralerts);
};
```

and this is the main call of the function :

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.getAlerts();

        this.tableData1 = {
            headerRow: ['ID', 'Alert Text', 'Type', 'CreatedAt'],
            dataRows: this.useralerts
                  };
        console.log(this.tableData1.dataRows);   
    }
```

I was passing the data inside the subscribe like this :

```
this.tabledata1.dataRows=this.useralerts;
```

this helped me preview the data inside the table component but I am getting the previously visited components in the main page ( like it's the router module stcuk inside subscription ) 
when I removed that line I am unable to save the data from GET request into the array `TableData1.datarows`

this a screenshot of the display in my console : 
[image]

as it shows the data is successfully saved inside subscribe but , outside it is "undefined"

could you please provide me with an explanation to this I am stuck for like 2 days now

this a preview of the pbm I am facing with routing & display : 
[image]

Comment: Things are happening asynchronously and your `console.log(this.tableData1.dataRows);` line is happening before your server response comes back. You should move the setup of `this.tableData1` to inside your subscribe to solve this.

Comment: If your problem is that your view is not updated correctly, try something like {{(useralerts | async)}}. If it isn't, more information will be needed for a good answer.

Comment: I was doing like that but now I have the problem that the view is showing previously visited components , so I thought may be the subscribe was the cause , that's why I asked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar trouble, the way i solved i just call a set function outside of the subscribe in your case would be something like this:

```
getAlerts(){
 this.ChatAlertsService.getAlerts()
        .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log('ngon Init', data);
                this.setUsersArray(data['result']);
                 console.log('inside subscribe user_alerts', this.useralerts);

            },
            (error) => console.log(error));
    console.log('outside subscribe user_alerts', this.useralerts);
};

setUsersArray(data){
   this.useralerts= data;
}
```